# Trying to find longest string in a list using recursion. Why am I getting none?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why am I getting none?

```
def find_longest(long:list):

    for i in range(len(long)):
        if long[i] == '' or long[i] == []:
            return long
        elif len(long[i])>len(long[i-1]):
            max_length = find_longest(long[i])

            return long.append(max_length)

print(find_longest(longest_strings))
```

Answer (score 3):

Append doesn't return anything. You need to append then return the list.

```
def find_longest(long:list):

    for i in range(len(long)):
        if long[i] == '' or long[i] == []:
            return long
        elif len(long[i])>len(long[i-1]):
            max_length = find_longest(long[i])
            long.append(max_length)
            return long
```

The reason for this is because `list` is a mutable data type and append simply mutates the list not create a new instance of the list with the new data attached.

A much better way to find the longest string would be something along these lines:

```
def longest_string(strings):
    return max(strings, key=lambda x: len(x))

values = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd']

print longest_string(values)
```

Comment: Given the OP is mutating the passed in list, they don't actually have to return anything.

Comment: But they are printing the return.

Comment: Your call to `max` could be simplified even further by replacing the `lambda` with the built-in it calls:  `max(strings, key=len)`.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know that! I will have to start doing it that way.